# JTAppleCalendar preselect current date without triggering isSelected

Tags: ios, swift, cell, jtapplecalendar

Hi I'm trying to show the JTAppleCalendar with the current date selected but I would like it not to trigger the isSelected because I would like to show a timepicker when the user actually selects a date instead of being triggered when the Calendar loads with the current date

**Current code when the a cell is selected**

```
func handleCellSelected(view: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState){
    guard let validCell = view as? CalendarCell else {return}
    if validCell.isSelected{
        validCell.selectedView.isHidden = false
        if remindMeOnDay.isOn{
            self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMMM dd"
            if userPickedDate{
                dateSelected.text = formatter.string(for:userDate)


                SelectTime(sender: validCell)

                //self.dateSelected.text = self.formatter.string(from: cellState.date)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300), execute: {
                    self.updateTableView(tableView: self.tableView)
                })
            }

        }

        userPickedDate = true

    }else {
        validCell.selectedView.isHidden = true
    }

 }
```

**The trigger Code**

```
@IBAction func remindMeOnDaySwitch(_ sender: UISwitch?) {
let date = Date()


    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadData()
    //Shows the calendar with current date selected
    if remindMeOnDay.isOn{
        calendarView.scrollToDate(date)
        self.calendarView.selectDates([NSDate() as Date])




        //self.calendarView.selectDates([NSDate() as Date])

        if !checkForNotificationAccess(){
            notificationAlert()
            remindMeOnDay.isOn = false
        }

    }
    if !remindMeOnDay.isOn {
        userDate = date
        userPickedDate = false
    }
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

[The result I'm getting](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3o6vXNoecMKLYKnHos)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the following code:

```
calendarView.selectDates([Date()], triggerSelectionDelegate: false)
```

Comment: Hi, so I changed the selectDates code but validCell.isSelected is still true which in turn triggers my timepicker to launch. ideas?

Comment: Well if you `timePicker` launch depends on whether or not the cell is selected, then how do you wish to differentiate between an user selection VS a programatic selection?

Comment: hmm I don't know, would it be possible to add something like a hidden view on top of the calendar cell or something that would trigger the timepicker? I just thought there would be an easy way to launch the calendar with the current date selected and then trigger something else when the user picked a date

Comment: there is. I think youre doing something complicated -> can you join me here https://gitter.im/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar

Comment: Hey I got it working, kinda, I set the userpickeddate = true inside de didselectdate function. Now every date works as expected except the current date selected which require a double tap and the launches two timepickers.

Comment: I added an upgrate for you. Now it is possible to check to see user selection VS a programatic selection. Now you can check `cellState.selectionChangedProgramatically`. Let me know if this works for you. Currently the upgrade is on master branch. Follow the instructions [Here](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/wiki/Common-Questions) to test it. Let me know if this works for you.